# ForeignKey returns id when editing the form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

This is my model

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.ForeignKey(Title, verbose_name="Title")
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title.title
```

I'm using a form to replace the ForegnKey field by a CharField

```
class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(label = "Title")
    class Meta:
        model = Category

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CategoryForm
```

My Title model

```
class Title(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Title", max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Everything works well when I add and display categories but when I try to edit a category, I get the ForeignKey ID in the title field. I want it to be the title string. Any way to do that ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Why do you have a Title model with just one field? Why not just a models.CharField title on Category?

Comment: The title field is just an example. I'm using it as foreign key because it will be use by other applications. There is more code in the model but I sent just the essential. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed that by making the title unique and adding to_field option to the ForeignKey in my category class. This is the code :

```
class Title(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Title", max_length=200, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.ForeignKey(Title, verbose_name="Title", to_field='title')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title.title
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't check this solution (i can't create test application now) and i don't sure that it works.

Try to add `exclude = ("title", )` as CategoryForm member. Also maybe you'll need to override save() (and maybe other) method of CategoryForm.